DrawingView draw - save - load
TLDR: Unable to convert Stream to ObservableCollection<IDrawingLine>
Having a DrawingView:
<toolkit:DrawingView 
         DrawingLineStarted="Signature_DrawingLineStarted"
         ShouldClearOnFinish="False" 
         BackgroundColor="Transparent"
         IsMultiLineModeEnabled="True" 
         Lines="{Binding Signature, Mode=OneWayToSource}"/>

I'm able to get the related Stream of the drawing like this:
Stream SignatureStream = await (DrawingView.GetImageStream(Signature, new Size(150, 150),
                    Microsoft.Maui.Graphics.Colors.Transparent, cts.Token));

Now I can save this drawing as a byte array into an external file. But my question is the following:
How can I load the drawing back again?
I can get the Stream from the file, but I haven't found a way to put the Stream content back into the DrawingView.

You are saving an image of the drawing, there is no way to reload it from that data.  Instead you need to serialize the Lines property

You can use JSON serialization and deserialization to load the drawing back again.
public ObservableCollection<IDrawingLine> Lines { get; set; } = [];

public ObservableCollection<IDrawingLine> RestoredLines { get; set; } = [];

private void TransferWithJson()
{
    string jsonData = JsonSerializer.Serialize(Lines);

    // Save jsonData to database

    ObservableCollection<DrawingLine>? deserializedLines = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<ObservableCollection<DrawingLine>?>(jsonData);
    if (deserializedLines != null)
    {
        RestoredLines.Clear();
        foreach (DrawingLine line in deserializedLines)
        {
            RestoredLines.Add(line);
        }
    }
}

